# Oracle SQL to Select rows based on case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table with the following fields

```
ID          Category    AgingSet    Amount
K-218660115 02          STD         -159
K-218660115 03          STD           60
K-218660115 04          STD           90
K-218660115 05          STD            6
K-218660115 06          BDSTD        156
```

My sql select should return the last row i.e.

```
K-218660115 06          BDSTD        156
```

if STD aging set is non zero. Had all the STD aging set been set to 0 , my SQL select would return

```
K-218660115 02          BDSTD             0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why should your select return the last row? Because it has "BD" along with "STD"? Or because it has largest category (06)? Or because its amount (156) is the highest? **Also**, what does "had all the STD aging set been set to 0" mean? Column AGINGSET contains strings, not numbers. Did you mean to say that AMOUNT is set to 0? IF so, why would you return a row whose CATEGORY = 02, but AGINGSET belongs to the last row? Maybe the whole concept is clear to you, but it certainly isn't to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic seems a little hard to follow.  You seem to want conditional logic based on whether or not the sum is `0` for the `'STD'` values.

This should return what you want on the data you provided:

```
select id, category, 'BDSTD' as agingSet, amount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by category) as seqnum,
             sum(case when agingSet = 'Std' and amount <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as num_not_zero
      from t
     ) t
where (num_not_zero = 0 and seqnum = 1) or
      (num_not_zero > 0 and agingSet = 'BDSTD');
```